# Will the "readonly" flag for USB drives mark it as read-only for other devices?

Tags: windows, usb

I am putting a movie on a USB drive, and I want to make it readonly to avoid corruption when plugged into my TV. Will the "readonly" apply for the whole drive or just the OS?

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no harm in setting the file as read only.  However, marking the file read only will likely do nothing to protect the file.  Pretty much every TV that can read a USB stick is running an alternate OS, like a custom Android or Linux OS.  I would not expect any of them to honor FAT32 or NTFS file system attributes, like read only.  That being said, generally you wouldnt have corruption unless the file was open *for writing* which it wouldnt be.  That doesnt mean it cant happen, but its unlikely.

Comment: When I pulled the power from my TV, it got corrupt.

Comment: @user1513520 well thats a hardware failure.  Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Android or Linux (Android IS based on Linux) don't honor filesystem attributes? That would be one hell of an omission.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Android has a linux kernel, yes.  But it is not a linux OS.  And Linux has never honored NTFS file permissions.  Thats why people boot linux to specifically bypass NTFS permissions and flags.